# how to return a char* array from a function of strcpy and store it in another char* array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, heap-memory

I have created a function of Strcpy to copy one string into another.It works perfectly fine when two **char[] arrays** are pass through it but when char* arrays are passed it is gives  segmentation fault (core dumped) error. How to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

char* Strcpy ( char* s1 , const char* s2 )
{
while(*s2 != '\0')
{
*(s1)=*(s2);
s1++;
s2++;
}
*s1='\0';

return s1;
}

int main()
{

/*char t1[]="HelloWorld";  //it is working fine for both these arrays
char t2[]="TestString";*/

char* t1="HelloWorld";    //Segmentation fault
char* t2="TestString";

char* r=Strcpy(t1,t2);

cout<<r<<endl;

cout << t1;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to copy into constant literal string space.  This area of memory is  protected against writes.

Comment: That code should generate some warnings. You should take those seriously.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your strcpy function works on these:

Example 1:

```
char t1[]="HelloWorld";  // you are defining arrays of characters in the data 
char t2[]="TestString";  // segment.  This are of memory has read/write access.
                         // You have effectively allocated and initiaized 
                         // 22 bytes of data in read/write memory.
```

Whereas here (example 2):

```
char* t1="HelloWorld";  // you are defining pointers in the data segment.
char* t2="TestString";  // these pointers point to data that is stored in
                        // the BSS segment, which is strictly read-only.
                        // You have allocated and initialized 16 bytes 
                        // (2 pointers) in the data segment, and 22 bytes
                        // in read only memory.
```

Segmentation fault occurs when Strcpy() tries to overwrite protected data in the BSS segment.

There are several ways to fix this.  You could, as in example 1, allocate enough memory for your destination string in global data space, or allocate memory on the stack, or yet again allocate some memory in the heap.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// read-only  BSS segment.
const char* src = "HelloWorld";  // length: 10 + 1 null terminating character. 

// global memory alllocation in DATA segment.
char global_mem_dest[11];
 
int main()
{
    strcpy(global_mem_dest, src);

    char stack_space_dest[11];    // on the stack. 
    strcpy(stack_space_dest, src);

    char* heap_mem_dest_1 = (char*)malloc(strlen(src) + 1);  // on the heap
    if (heap_mem_dest_1)
    {
        strcpy(heap_mem_dest_1, src);
        free(heap_mem_dest_1);
    }

    char* heap_mem_dest_2 = strdup(src);   // on the heap, method 2.
    if (heap_mem_dest_2)
        free(heap_mem_dest_2);

    // Note that method 2 allocates space and copies a string in one
    // function call. This is probably what you are looking for.

    char* heap_mem_dest_3 = new char[strlen(src) + 1];   // on the heap, the c++ way.
    strcpy(heap_mem_dest_3, src);
    delete[] heap_mem_dest_3;

    return 0;
}
```

Since strcpy() returns a pointer to the destination string, which you already have, its return value is not very useful, and is usually ignored.